# Having issues centering bottom pinned nav bar for bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the standard pinned to bottom nav bar that is stock out of bootstrap. The nav bar has three several list items all wrapped in a container, row and column. I am using the center-block class provided in the current bootstrap framework that should center this entire element in the nav bar. But it's not. Can anyone help?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 center-block">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#team-details">Team Details</a></li>
                    <li class="divider">&raquo;</li>
                    <li><a href="#team-members-details">Team Members</a></li>
                    <li class="divider">&raquo;</li>
                    <li><a href="#final-review">Final Review</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

Nothing custom for the styles except on the divider class which is just padding.

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/12t0ft02/)**

Add `text-center` to the `<div class="row">`

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12 center-block">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#team-details">Team Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider">&raquo;</li>
                    <li><a href="#team-members-details">Team Members</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider">&raquo;</li>
                    <li><a href="#final-review">Final Review</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```